# NVDIA Digits のModel学習中に表示されるグラフの意味を教えてください。

Tags: 機械学習, 深層学習

NVIDIA DIGITSの学習中に表示されるグラフの意味、loss(train) accuracy(val) loss(val)のそれぞれの意味は何でしょうか？
[image: グラフの画像]

Answer (score 1):

lossは正解とどれくらい離れているかという数値。0に近づくほど正解に近い。
accuracyはそのまま「正確性」100%に近いほど正解に近い。
(train)というのは、学習時の値。(val)はvalidation時の値。
データは学習にのみ使われるものと、validation、つまりテストにのみ使われるものに別けられます。loss(train)が下がっているのに、(accuracy)の値が改善しない場合は過学習に陥っている可能性があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
上図でloss(val)が若干高めになっていますが、これもvalidationデータの結果の値が正解と乖離していて、過学習気味ということでしょうか？

Comment: accuracyが十分高いので過学習気味ということはないと思います。

手前味噌&他のシステムですが、過学習の時のグラフ載せてる記事がありますのでご参考までに

http://qiita.com/hidesuke/items/0342f899440394002708

Comment: どうも有難うございます。ただ、まだいくつかはっきりしない事があるのですが、accuracyとはvalidationデータに対して認識を行った場合のスコア値（正解らしさ）と考えてよろしいでしょうか？
あとvalidationデータが学習時に使われないと言うことですが、上のグラフの処理を行った後に、更に別のデータを使って認識率を検証することは無駄なことでしょうか？

Comment: digitsでは表示されていませんが、train時もaccuracyは計算できます。(caffeでどうするかは知りませんがchainerにはaccuracyを取得する方法があります)

別のデータを使って認識率を検証するのは意味はありますよ。
学習して、学習結果を用いて実際の問題を解くことに利用するわけですから。
それが意味がないと思われるのであれば、何のために学習をさせているのかわかりかねます。